# Disabled text box is enabled after page reload

Tags: javascript

I have a simple js validation function that checks if a checkbox is checked, if it's then the textbox input is enabled for the user, but when the checkbox is not checked it automatically makes the textbox field disabled.

The problem is that when after saving the page in the AJAX with not checked field, causes that the textbox field is again enabled even the checkbox is **not checked**, when I check it again 2 times then the function works again, but each time the page reloads and save previously selected values the function does not works at is should.

What I am doing wrong? Is there a different way to prevent this behavior?

```
function enableTextBodField() {

 var checkboxField= document.querySelector('.checkbox');
 var textBoxField= document.querySelector('.textBoxField');

 if (checkboxField.checked == false)
 {
    textBoxField.disabled = true;
 }
 else if (checkboxField.checked == true)
 {
    textBoxField.disabled = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hello, can you share a working code snippet? with html fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the state of that textbox in browser localStorage and work it out from there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var textboxState = localStorage.getItem("txtboxState"); // Get state from localstorage
    var textBoxField= document.querySelector('.textBoxField');
    var checkboxField= document.querySelector('.checkbox');

    if(textboxState != "" || textboxState != NULL){
      if(textboxState = "hidden"){
       textBoxField.disabled = true;
       checkboxField.checked = false;
      }else{
        if(textboxState == "visible"){
          textBoxField.disabled = false;
          checkboxField.checked = true;
        }
      }
    }else{
       textBoxField.disabled = false;
       checkboxField.checked = false;
    }

});

function enableTextBodField() {
 var checkboxField= document.querySelector('.checkbox');
 var textBoxField= document.querySelector('.textBoxField');

 if (checkboxField.checked == false)
 {
    textBoxField.disabled = true;
    localStorage.setItem("txtboxState","hidden"); // Set state in localstorage variable
 }
 else if (checkboxField.checked == true)
 {
    textBoxField.disabled = false;
    localStorage.setItem("txtboxState","visible"); // Set state in localstorage variable
 }
}
```

Comment: Why the field is `hidden` or `visible` I do not want to hide these fields.

Comment: they are disabled not hidden or visible, we are using hidden or visible as words to check the state of the textbox. we save a variable in the localStorage and set its value to either "hidden" or "visible" accordingly and when you reload the page the document will get the value of the variable we stored in the localStorage and if the value is "hidden" it will disable the textbox and if the value is "visible" it will enable the textbox and check or uncheck checkbox accordingly.

Comment: Can we use instead of "hidden" or "visible" just "disabled" or "enabled" that are only keywords that we can use to describe it am I right?

Comment: you can use any keyword or even integers for example 0 for hidden or 1 for visible. but make sure you check for the values you set it to when the document is ready.